# 500 error when trying to add expires header to .htaccess

Tags: performance, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to add a far future expires header by editing my .htaccess file

this is recommended in the yslow performance rules

but when I do, I get a 500 internal server error

here's the code I'm using, any body know what's up?

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
```

Comment: In case of an error, you should always first look into the error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I didn't have mod_expires in this apache build, that will fix it

Comment: Unfortunately, in my experience, mod_expires isn't built into Apache by default.  That's not the only common module that isn't either (mod_headers also isn't as I recall).