# Adding "expires headers" is causing error 500

Tags: .htaccess

Ok, so I was testing my website at https://gtmetrix.com/ and they are recommending to add expires headers to .htaccess.

After doing some research it turns out its a good thing so I added this to my file.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

But it is causing error 500. unable to load the page.
a fellow stackoverflow is having similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439180/500-error-when-trying-to-add-expires-header-to-htaccess) and tried to follow their "solve" but still nothing.

this is my entire .htaccess code

```
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

What's causing the 500 error here?

edit: Even tho I removed the expires headers from the file, it still shows error 500. Did I break some server or something?

Comment: Was the HTTP to HTTPS redirect already present in your `.htaccess` file? The code you added should not cause an error, even if mod_expires is not installed, because it is enclosed in an `<IfModule>` container.

Comment: I removed the entire ``.htaccess`` file and it loads the file, but I remember some months ago when i set the domain, I created the file to make the convertion from http to https as some links i used were solely on http. but that shouldnt be an issue anymore since I changed/removed those

Comment: Well, the reason I ask about the HTTP to HTTPS redirect (the first 3 lines in your file) is that those are the only directives (from what you've posted) that could cause a 500 error. But if those directives have always been present in your `.htaccess` file, then maybe it's something else. If you've removed the entire `.htaccess` file and that resolves the 500 error then it's certainly something about the `.htaccess` that triggers this error. How are you editing the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: _“What's causing the 500 error here?”_ - that’s a question you should “ask” the server error log – no one else can answer this more easy.